# Coded UI doesn't launch testing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I have a hand written coded ui test with about 120 test cases. It is working well with IE but I want to run in chrome (or in Edge). I have installed the Cross Browser Selenium components with the chromedriver. After the installation I have changed my code with `BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";` line.
Actually it launches the chrome (68.0.3440.75) but then it fails with this exception :

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: A
>   exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to
>   the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:4334/session/74ce571a635c376d0982b7f59dc31f3b/title.
>   The status of the exception was ConnectFailure, and the message was:
>   Unable to connect to the remote server.

The chromedriver is 2.25 which I know  it's not compatible with my chrome, but If I upgrade the chromedriver with the latest version, then it launches and immediately closes itself.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Selenium version ?

Comment: If I see it well here it's 1.7   [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AtinBansal.SeleniumcomponentsforCodedUICrossBrowserTesting)